# using Jmeter with non-GUI for test plan

Tags: jmeter

i have faced a weird problem
i run 300 users simultaneously to log in to a website and read a file 
i used the non-GUI mode to do this test plan
my problem is that this test plan have passed for just one time then when i run it again it get error then i tried to reduce the number of users to 200 and it passed but again after a while it did not.
Here is what i get:

`Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM warning: ignoring option PermSize=64m; support
 was removed in 8.0
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM warning: ignoring option MaxPermSize=128m; sup
port was removed in 8.0
Creating summariser <summary>
Created the tree successfully using C:\Users\samo\Dropbox\Jmeter\jmetet\Reading_
script.jmx
Starting the test @ Mon Jul 07 13:24:11 GMT+03:00 2014 (1404728651964)
Waiting for possible shutdown message on port 4445
summary +   1980 in    48s =   41.6/s Avg:  5536 Min:     6 Max: 21171 Err:   77
2 (38.99%) Active: 300 Started: 300 Finished: 0
summary +   1272 in  40.1s =   31.7/s Avg:  3257 Min:     3 Max: 39796 Err:    3
1 (2.44%) Active: 192 Started: 300 Finished: 108
summary =   3252 in  77.4s =   42.0/s Avg:  4644 Min:     3 Max: 39796 Err:   80
3 (24.69%)
summary +   1203 in    70s =   17.2/s Avg:  6020 Min:     3 Max: 69837 Err:    5
8 (4.82%) Active: 84 Started: 300 Finished: 216
summary =   4455 in   107s =   41.5/s Avg:  5016 Min:     3 Max: 69837 Err:   86
1 (19.33%)
summary +    608 in   100s =    6.1/s Avg:  6753 Min:     3 Max: 78722 Err:    4
2 (6.91%) Active: 7 Started: 300 Finished: 293
summary =   5063 in   137s =   36.9/s Avg:  5224 Min:     3 Max: 78722 Err:   90
3 (17.84%)
summary +     37 in    41s =    0.9/s Avg:  4880 Min:     4 Max: 37736 Err:    1
7 (45.95%) Active: 0 Started: 300 Finished: 300
summary =   5100 in   142s =   35.9/s Avg:  5222 Min:     3 Max: 78722 Err:   92
0 (18.04%)
Tidying up ...    @ Mon Jul 07 13:26:34 GMT+03:00 2014 (1404728794704)
... end of run`

what did i miss to face this problem?
and how to know if the problem is out of memory or something else

Answer (score 0, accepted):

hi guys i have figured out the problem

1- First of all i changed the heap size in the properties file in the bin folder to be:
BEFORE: set HEAP=-Xms512m -Xmx512m      AFTER: set HEAP=-Xms2048m -Xmx2048m

2- Removed all the listeners i used before

3- Set the ramp up time in the thread group interface to be 180.
Ramp-Up before making changes was set to 1 which is not realistic because Jmeter can not run all the 300 users in 1 second

4- Set the loop count in the thread group interface to be 2

the error that i get before making these change was

> java.net.SocketException,Non HTTP response message: Connection reset

which means that the server closed the connection

hope this can help someone out there